# Как сделать проверку, вызвана ли функция в Lua?

Tags: android, lua, android-button, coronasdk

При одновременном нажатии двух клавиш должна запускаться некоторая функция. Как сделать проверку о том, что две клавиши нажаты одновременно в Corona SDK? Я думаю, при вызове функции одной кнопки, нужна проверка, не вызвана ли функция второй кнопки.

Сама задача:

*При одновременном нажатии клавиш `buttonTop` и `buttonRight` поворачивать объект на 45° методом `object:rotate(45)`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не имел дела с Corona SDK, но скорее всего необходимо сделать таблицу, где ключи -- ID кнопок, а значения булевы. Каждый обработчик кнопки устанавливает значение своей кнопки в `true`. После того, как все клавиши обработались (метод `update`, может быть) гоним проверки комбинаций, а после обнуляемм таблицу.

P. S.: возможно, существуют нативные функции/таблицы для данных целей.

Псевдокод решения:

```
keyhandlers = {}

create_keyhandler = function(keyid)
    return function()
        keyhandlers[keyid] = true
    end
end
update = function() -- This function must be called after all keyhandlers
    ...
    -- handle pressed keys
    if keyhandlers['Top'] and keyhandlers['Right'] then
        object:rotate(45)
    end
    ...
    -- reset keyhandlers
    keyhandlers = {}
    ...
end

addhandler('buttonTop', create_keyhandler('Top')) -- replace addhandler with real function or something else
addhandler('buttonRight', create_keyhandler('Right'))
```

Comment: Как насчёт ввести переменную со значением `false`, а при нажатии на кнопку менять ее на `true`? Потом можно сделать проверку на true в функции другой кнопки.

Comment: Я просто предложил универсальное решение. Можно сделать функцию-конструктор регистраторов событий. Опять же, все клавиши обнуляются оптом, просто `table_of_keys = {}`. В скором времени приведу псевдокод решения.

Comment: Опять же неизвесто, в каком порядке будут запущены функции, а это означает дублирование кода.